# Why can't I connect Jenkins remotely?

Tags: jenkins, wifi, vpn, remote-connection

I'm working in a company xxx and due to Covid-19 we are all working from home.

When trying to connect Jenkins website I get from chrome :

```
This site can’t be reached
jenkins.xxx.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

1. Connected to the internet via WiFi.
2. I have to be connected via VPN to enter Jenkins website.
3. When connected via mobile hotspot and VPN, the website works.
4. Working on Mac OS - Catalina.

Thanks ;)

Comment: You need to address this with your IT department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your Jenkins server is not publicly accessible (which is good for your Jenkins server security). This is the reason why it works in the internal network (you are connected to this via VPN) and does not work when you are not connected via VPN.